# Find maximum volume of carry on when the total length of the sides is 45 inches

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

My current problem is finding a formula to put the equation for volume, $V=xyz$, where $x+y+z=45$ in terms of just $x$ and $y$. So far, I have come up with

$V=45xy-x^2y-xy^2$

but when I try to solve for the critical points of the function using the partial derivatives of the function that I found,

$\frac{\delta V}{\delta x}=45y-2xy-y^2$

and

$\frac{\delta V}{\delta y}=45x-x^2-2yx$

all I get are the points $(0,45)$ and $(45,0)$. These are obviously the minimums of the function as they both cause $V=0$. How should I go about this instead of my original equation? Or am I just screwing up when solving for 0 with the partials I'm getting?

Comment: Do you know Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: I do not, and the chapter on them is the chapter after the one this exercise is under so I figured I wouldn't have to use them

Answer (score 1):

I think it remains to solve $$45-2x-y=0\\45-x-2y=0$$ which imply $x=y=15$ and consequently $z=15$.